# Adding the instance of a custom class to a Pane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a main class which contains the user interface and the following eventhandler.

```
public Pane canvas;
menuBarItemH.setOnAction(e1 -> {
    Flock.SeparationRange = separateDistance;
    Flock.DetectionRange = detectDistance;

    Flock flock = new Flock();

    for (int i=0; i < numberOfGreenPassengers; i++) {
        Passenger passenger = new Passenger(10, 10, 10, Color.BROWN, ball);
        passenger.setCenterX(10);
        passenger.setCenterY(10);
        passenger.setRadius(10);
        passenger.setSpeed( greenPassengerSpeed );
        passenger.setMaxTurnTheta( greenPassengerMaxTheta );
        flock.addPassenger(passenger);      

        canvas.getChildren().add(passenger);  
    }
```

Passenger and Flock are separate classes and after creating an instance of each and calling methods on the instance of Passenger, I am attempting to add the resulting instance to the Pane which is called canvas.

Here is the constructor for Passenger:

```
public class Passenger extends Circle {

  protected Point location = new Point(0,0);
  private int currentTheta;
  public Color color;
  protected static Dimension map = new Dimension( 500, 500 );
  private double currentSpeed; 
  private int maxTurnTheta;

  static Circle ball8 = new Circle(5, Color.BROWN);

  Passenger(int x, int y, int theta, Color passengerColor, Circle ball) {
    location.x = x;
    location.y = y;
    currentTheta = theta;
    color = passengerColor;
    ball8 = ball;
  }
```

And for Flock:

```
Flock() {
  passengers = new Vector(40,1);
}
```

I have made Passenger an extension of Circle and implemented a circle as part of the constructor to try and make it compatible with the Pane named canvas in the main class.

The flock class contains various methods for controlling the movements of the objects created from the Passenger class.

My question is if there is any way to add the flock/passenger objects to the Pane as a node and if not if there is an alternative way of adding objects which contain visual elements such as shapes but which also contain other methods in addition to the basic constructor for a shape to a javafx scene.

Thanks

Comment: You don't ever seem to set the properties of your `Passenger` object (e.g. `centerX`, `centerY`, `radius`, etc). By default it will have these all set to zero, so you are creating a zero-radius circle. Consequently, you won't actually see anything when it is added to the pane.

Comment: Hi James. They are set in the main class when the object passenger is created. In the for loop I have included: Passenger passenger = new Passenger(10, 10, 10, Color.BROWN, ball);

Comment: Where? I don't see anywhere you actually set `centerX`, `centerY` or `radius`. (If that code is there, you need to post it.) Those values are just used for specific fields defined in your subclass, as far as I can see. Can you do `System.out.println(passenger.getRadius())`, for example, to verify the radius is non-zero?

Comment: I added the extra properties and set them but the circles still don't appear when I run the program...

Comment: But as I just explained, the circle you are adding to the pane has zero radius.

Comment: This is my edited for loop:        for (int i=0; i < numberOfGreenPassengers; i++) {
   
               Passenger passenger = new Passenger(10, 10, 10, Color.BROWN, ball);
               passenger.setCenterX(10);
               passenger.setCenterY(10);
               passenger.setRadius(10);
               passenger.setSpeed( greenPassengerSpeed );
               passenger.setMaxTurnTheta( greenPassengerMaxTheta );
               flock.addPassenger(passenger);  
               
               canvas.getChildren().add(passenger);  
               
              
          }

Comment: OK, please [edit] the question to include that code (it is basically unreadable in a comment). Better, create and post a [MCVE]; it's pretty much impossible to tell what you're doing wrong from the code available.

Comment: That code works when I run it: I see a circle of radius `10` centered at `[10,10]` (obviously, only one circle is visible since they all have the same location and size).